# schwarz class and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

Schwarz and $L^2$ both have the property that the Fourier transform is defined and bijective as a self-map of these spaces.  Are they related in anyway or is this coincidence? (i.e. dual in some sense, or perhaps both arising from some more general construction.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$L^2$ is where it all starts;   from it new such spaces (including $\mathcal S$, for Schwartz with the **t**) can be constructed in a routine way. Let $w$ be a   locally integrable function on $\mathbb R$ such that $\inf w>0$. The space
$$S_w=\{f: wf\in L^2 \ \text{ and } \ w\hat f\in L^2\}$$
is a subset of $L^2$ on which the Fourier transform $\mathcal F$ is a bijection.

If $w\equiv 1$, we have $L^2$ itself. 
Another example  is given by $w(x)=(1+x^2)^{p/2}$, for any $p>0$.

The property of being mapped onto itself by $\mathcal F$ is preserved under intersection of function spaces. Taking the intersection of $S_w$ with $w(x)=(1+x^2)^{p/2}$ over all $p>0$, we get $\mathcal S$. (To see that this agrees with the usual definition, observe that derivatives remain in this intersection, and that the integral norm of  a sufficiently high derivative  controls the supremum of a function.)

We   get something smaller than $\mathcal S$ with $w=\exp{|x|}$; this space is still nontrivial (contains the Gaussian function). I suspect that beyond $w=\exp(x^2)$  the space  $S_w$ becomes trivial, but don't have a proof.